# Implementing Greater Than operation using SQL wildcard

Tags: sql, wildcard

I have some serialized data inside a relational database table, like:

```
ID | VALUE
60 | "A=18, D=78"
70 | "D=4, A=18"
80 | "A=21, C=44"
```

The system can perform queries for searching a particular value using wildcards:

```
LIKE '%A=18%' (returns the ID:60 and ID:70 registers)
```

But now I require to implement the Greater Than operator in a similar way.

Is it possible using wildcards?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean like "...LIKE '%A>18%' ?

Comment: Yes... if that syntax worked.

Comment: I doubt it. Can't think of anything. Your example above is pure text-matching, not maths so not sure how it would interpret A>18. MySql has REGEXP to do regular expressions in a WHERE clause but that is not for maths, although you might still be able to use it if you are using MySql

Comment: Not without splitting the components into individual values, and then doing a greater than against the numeric values.  Or, you know, normalizing the table.

Comment: how can data be compared using REGEXP?

Comment: @user1275011:- I dont think using REGEXP you can perform math operations

Comment: I know the solution is normalizing the table or using a NoSQL database, but this system is old, and I'm just implementing new requirements over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible. It will be treated as a string literal.

When you say `LIKE '%A=10%'` then `A=10` is treated as a string for text matching not as an expression to evaluate.

So if you write like `LIKE '%A>10%'` then it would take `A>10` as a string and not perform any math on it and will result in rows which match the text and in your case it would not return anything.

Comment: I wonder if applying a mask or using wildcard ranges, that functionality could be achieved. The problem is that the only alternative is to deserialize in memory, but it would be extremely expensive.

Comment: @user1275011:- If you want to achieve that then probably you need to split that. But I am not sure if that would be a good approach!

Comment: Anything faster than retrieving all registers to memory would do it.

Comment: @user1275011:- Normalisation would be the best, safest and most efficient way in your case. And it would help you in future also otherwise it would be a heck :(

Comment: I Understand the correct way to do it is normalization, but the system is old, and cannot be migrated to a different data model.

Comment: @user1275011:- Then I am really afraid as there is no way which I can think of implementing it. May be you can wait for some other answers(*although the chances are low*)

Comment: I can wait a couple weeks... I will try stored procedures or something.

Comment: @user1275011:- Thats your call. But I am quite sure you will not find any efficient way for that. Good luck!

Comment: I have a field records like `1-2`,`3-4`,`6-1`,`10-3`, now how can i select first value is greater than 3?, means i want `6-1`,`10-3` which has greater than 3.